# Macro detect KDE or GNOME in qt4

Tags: c++, macros, qt4, detect, kde-plasma

I have a problem to detect when used in GNOME or KDE
operating system that runs the application.
The program I am doing QT4, and I have trouble feeling of look-
in the systray, so I pass it to KDE, but which is not
macro to do so.
PD: I use KDE and C / C.
I search in web and I see this:
[Creating executable for Windows using Qt on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963611/creating-executable-for-windows-using-qt-program-in-linux)
But for KDE?

Greetings Alejandro Espinosa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt does not provide this kind of defines based on the desktop environment. If you need to know the desktop environment at compilation time, then your best bet would be to modify your build system to pass the necessary defines to the compiler. The desktop environment can be concluded by different prerequisites such as environment variables, availability of applications, libraries or headers. The choice depends on what you're trying to do.

For instance, if you take the environment inspection route, KDE defines the KDE_FULL_SESSION variable whereas GNOME has the DESKTOP_SESSION variable set to "gnome". FYI, that's how Qt detects the DE at run time.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with help of bash by writing a script containing the given code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Now when you execute the code from Qprocess you can read the output of Qprocess and check what is the output of Qprocess.

```
{
QProcess chkdesk;
chkdesk.start("getenv");  //getenv is bash script 
qDebug() << chkdesk.readAll();  
}
```

Comment: See also [qgetenv](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qgetenv) for a better way to get the environment variable