# Create .exe file that can execute on linux and windows By QT creator

Tags: linux, windows, qt-creator, executable

I am trying to Create an application by using Qt Creator under Linux, I want to have an `.exe` file that can be run on both Windows and Linux platform ,how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator provides support for building and running Qt applications for desktop environments (Windows, Linux, FreeBSD and Mac OS) and mobile devices (Android, BlackBerry, Maemo, and MeeGo). Build settings allow you to switch between build targets. For mobile device targets, Qt Creator can generate an installation package, install it to a mobile device that is attached to the development computer and run it there. Installation packages can be published on the Ovi Store.

So you have to seperately build application for windows and linux to run your QT application. You can see more on [Creating executable for Windows using Qt on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963611/creating-executable-for-windows-using-qt-on-linux)

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker